# Android Kotlin - On image inside ImageView loaded

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

This is what I've tried

```
    Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(imgUrl)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable>{
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }

        })
        .into(holder.image)
```

First error on `object`:

Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable!, model: Any!, target: Target!, dataSource: DataSource!, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean defined in com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener

Second error on `Drawable`:

No type arguments expected for annotation class Target

Third error on second `override`:

'onResourceReady' overrides nothing

What is wrong here? Or are there any other solutions??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those errors occurs because you are importing the wrong version of Target class. You should import "Target" from com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target package.

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target


object : RequestListener<Drawable> {

    override fun onLoadFailed(
        e: GlideException?,
        model: Any?,
        target: Target<Drawable>?,
        isFirstResource: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onResourceReady(
        resource: Drawable?,
        model: Any?,
        target: Target<Drawable>?,
        dataSource: DataSource?,
        isFirstResource: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What about DataSource, what's that import?